# Solidity variable definition: (bool sent, )

Tags: solidity

In Solidity, this sentence:

```
(bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: _amount}("");
```

What is the sense of that "," after sent variable?

Any link to offcial documentation?

Many thanks.

Comment: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/control-structures.html?highlight=multiple#destructuring-assignments-and-returning-multiple-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`address.call` returns two things: the status of the call (as a boolean), and the returned data of the call (as bytes), in the form of a tuple. The type looks something like `(bool success, bytes data)`.

This is a [destructuring assignment](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/control-structures.html?highlight=multiple#destructuring-assignments-and-returning-multiple-values), as mentinoned by Richard Horrocks in the comments:

```
(bool foo, bytes bar) = someFunction()
```

It takes the values in the returned tuple, and assigns them to the variables `foo` and `bar`. If `someFunction` returns two (or more) values in the tuple, but we only care about the first one, we can write it as:

```
(bool foo, ) = someFunction()
```

In which case we are not assigning the second variable. Doing this can potentially save some gas. Note that the other way around is also possible:

```
(, bytes bar) = someFunction()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great explanation!!! Very clear.